# Compare char in Micro ASM 1.00

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086

How to compare two char, the first one is user input.

```
include 'emu8086.inc'

#make_COM#

ORG 100h

answer DW ?
score DW ?

MOV score, 0

PRINT "This is a 10 question Exam"

PUTC 13
PUTC 10
PUTC 13
PUTC 10

PRINT "1.) A is the Answer"
PUTC 13
PUTC 10
PRINT " A.)"
PUTC 13
PUTC 10
PRINT " B.)"
PUTC 13
PUTC 10
PRINT " C.)"
PUTC 13
PUTC 10
PRINT " D.)"
PUTC 13
PUTC 10
PRINT "Your Answer: "  
LEA     DI, buffer      
MOV     DX, 10     
CALL GET_STRING  
MOV answer, AX
PUTC 13
PUTC 10

MOV     SI, answer
CALL    print_string

CMP SI, answer
JE Correct
JMP result

Correct:
ADD score, 1
JMP result

result: 
PRINT "Your Score: "
CALL PRINT_NUM

RET

buffer DB "x"

DEFINE_SCAN_NUM
DEFINE_PRINT_NUM
DEFINE_PRINT_NUM_UNS
DEFINE_PRINT_STRING
DEFINE_GET_STRING

END
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> buffer DB "x"
> ```

This will not give you enough buffer space! If you stick with your definition of `mov dx, 10` then you need to change this into: `buffer db "1234567890"`. Since as I will explain 2 bytes will be enough this can become `buffer db "12"`

> ```
> LEA     DI, buffer
> MOV     DX, 10
> CALL GET_STRING
> MOV answer, AX
> ```

You don't seem to know how the *GET_STRING* procedure works! It stores your input zero-terminated in the DX bytes buffer at DS:DI.  Since your answer will be a single character, you need to define DX=2 and you can retrieve the answer through `mov ax, [di]` `mov answer, ax`. Hereafter  *answer* is a zero-terminated string having a single character for its contents.

> ```
> MOV     SI, answer
> CALL    print_string
> ```

Here you moved the contents of *answer* in SI. You need the address of a zero-terminated string to be passed to the *PRINT_STRING* procedure, so write: `lea si, answer` `call PRINT_STRING`

> ```
> CMP SI, answer
> JE Correct
> JMP result
> ```

Because of how you setup `SI` this compare will always return *Correct*. You have to compare the contents with a defined value: `mov al, [si]` `cmp al, "A"`(Hint: you wrote "A is the Answer")